# Jekyll fails to serve (Ruby incompatible library version)

Tags: ruby, jekyll

When trying to run `jekyll serve`, it seems to build correctly (though with warnings that I haven't been able to resolve), but then fails to serve. `jekyll build` completes, but the resulting files are missing the compiled CSS.

Output from `jekyll serve`:

```
Ignoring ffi-1.9.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.10
Ignoring curb-0.9.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine curb --version 0.9.3
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring ffi-1.9.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.10
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
Ignoring json-1.8.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.2
Ignoring thin-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine thin --version 1.6.1
Configuration file: /home/jtebert/OwnCloud/Projects/Programming/python/AMS/mockup/_config.yml
            Source: /home/jtebert/OwnCloud/Projects/Programming/python/AMS/mockup
       Destination: /home/jtebert/OwnCloud/Projects/Programming/python/AMS/mockup/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 1.404 seconds.
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require': incompatible library version - /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi_c.so (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/native.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/adapter/linux.rb:30:in `_configure'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:45:in `block in configure'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `each'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `configure'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:63:in `start'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/backend.rb:26:in `start'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:67:in `block in <class:Listener>'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/fsm.rb:120:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/fsm.rb:120:in `call'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/fsm.rb:91:in `transition_with_callbacks!'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/fsm.rb:57:in `transition'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/listen-3.0.6/lib/listen/listener.rb:90:in `start'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/jekyll-watch-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/watcher.rb:12:in `watch'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/jekyll-3.1.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:72:in `watch'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/jekyll-3.1.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:39:in `process'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/jekyll-3.1.3/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        from /home/jtebert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/jekyll-3.1.3/bin/jekyll:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

When trying to start a Jekyll project, I did have to create a link of Ruby versions because it was looking for 'Ruby2.1', but I'm not sure if this is playing a role in the current problem: `ln -s /usr/bin/ruby '/usr/bin/ruby2.1'`.

According to my package manager, I've installed Ruby 2.3.0. But according to `which ruby`, I'm using 2.0.0 which it's getting from rvm: `/home/xxxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby`. And as I mentioned before, Jekyll seems to want v2.1 for something. I'm guessing these conflicting versions are somehow causing the problem, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: I have this same issue, but I do not have `rvm` installed. Any other guesses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem for me seemed to be rvm (which I'm not sure how I ended up using). The solution was to remove rvm with `rvm implode`, then reinstall jekyll with `gem install jekyll`. Both the warnings and errors disappeared, and it is serving properly.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had to install the `ffi` library with `gem`:

`gem install ffi`

This error is probably caused by an older version of the library installed in the system. `gem` then installs the correct version for your project.