# Unhandled exception when running Jekyll 4.0.0 using Bundler 1.17.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundle, rvm

I'm trying to set up automated deploys for Jekyll on my server, based on the [instructions here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/deployment/automated/#git-post-receive-hook). Whenever I run Jekyll commands on the server I get the following output:

```
$ bundle install && bundle exec jekyll -v
(bundle install output)
Bundle complete! 6 Gemfile dependencies, 30 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
    23: from /home/nk42/gems/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    22: from /home/nk42/gems/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    21: from /home/nk42/gems/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    20: from /home/nk42/gems/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    19: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
    18: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/exe/jekyll:8:in `require'
    17: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll.rb:206:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll.rb:206:in `require'
    15: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-2.0.1/lib/jekyll-sass-converter.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-2.0.1/lib/jekyll-sass-converter.rb:4:in `require'
    13: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-2.0.1/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-2.0.1/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:3:in `require'
    11: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `require_relative'
     9: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/lib/sassc/native.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/lib/sassc/native.rb:6:in `<module:SassC>'
     7: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/lib/sassc/native.rb:37:in `<module:Native>'
     6: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/lib/sassc/native.rb:37:in `require_relative'
     5: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/lib/sassc/native/lib_c.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/lib/sassc/native/lib_c.rb:4:in `<module:SassC>'
     3: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/lib/sassc/native/lib_c.rb:5:in `<module:Native>'
     2: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sassc-2.2.1/lib/sassc/native/lib_c.rb:10:in `<module:LibC>'
     1: from /home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/ffi-1.11.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:275:in `attach_function'
/home/nk42/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/ffi-1.11.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:275:in `attach': unhandled exception
```

I get the same output whether I use `bundle exec jekyll ...` or just `jekyll ...`, and it happens no matter what directory I'm in.

I'm able to run the same thing on my computer locally and it works. On both my computer and the server I'm running the following:

- rvm 1.29.9 (autolibs is disabled)
- ruby 2.6.3p62
- gem 3.0.3
- Bundler version 2.0.2
- Jekyll 4.0.0

The server is a Dreamhost Shared Hosting account, which runs Ubuntu 18.04, and I set up RVM using the instructions on [Dreamhost's help page](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/217185247-Ruby-Version-Manager-RVM-).

I suspect this is an issue with the Ruby/RVM installation, since the same project works locally, but I'm not sure how to debug this or where to look for information. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unhandled exception what? Is the last part of the error message missing?

Comment: No, that is the full output. The only thing I omitted was the area at the top where there's just a lot of output from the bundle install command - but I marked that with "(bundle install output)".

Comment: Why is part of the code running in `/home/nk42/gems/bin/`, and another part under RVM? Do you have two separate Ruby installations on your server? In any case it looks like the sassc library is failing to load. I.e. some sort of binary incompatibility, or missing dynamic library is my guess.

Comment: You could try to install the bundle into vendor instead of under RVM. In your project directory: `bundle install --path vendor`.

Comment: If all else fails delete ALL ruby installations, reinstall only one, and try again. Binary incompatibilities with libraries usually happen when you build the lib for one Ruby version, and then load it with another Ruby version. It's very easy to create this situation by mistake if you have a system Ruby and an RVM Ruby running on the same machine.

Comment: If it still keeps failing, downgrade Ruby to a 2.5.x version and try again. If it still keeps failing after that, raise an issue on github for jekyll.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a combination of problems. I'm still not entirely sure what the exact problem was, and unfortunately since I'm not an administrator on the server in question I can't dig too deeply into it.

Taking the following steps resolved the problem:

1. Run `gem install ffi; gem pristine --all`. After this, jekyll still gave a stack trace, but it looked more like the error on [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828951/jekyll-fails-to-serve-ruby-incompatible-library-version)
2. Remove RVM, per the troubleshooting steps on the thread linked in #1.